# Swift - DatePicker - Allow Only Valid Intervals

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, calendar, modulo

I am trying to configure two DatePickers, showing only time, where they must be a certain interval apart and match the interval.

For example:

Let's say I have two DatePickers, startTime and endTime. I also have a double variable called frequency.

If startTime is set to 8am and frequency is 2.5, I only want to be able to select 10:30am, 1pm, 3:30pm, 6pm, and so on from the endTime DatePicker.

This of course also goes the other way, where if the user has already set both the startTime and endTime values via their respective DatePickers, and then changes the frequency, the endTime should auto-update to the next closest value.

Example:

If startTime is 8am and endTime is 6pm and frequency is 2, all is well. If the user then changes frequency to be 3.5, endTime should auto-update to 6:30pm.

Hope that makes sense, here's some code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showsPicker: Bool = false
    @State private var frequency: Double = 1
    @State private var frequencyArray: [Double] = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
    @State private var startTime: Date = Date()
    @State private var endTime: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Frequency: \(frequency.formatted())")
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.blue)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    showsPicker.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if showsPicker {
                Picker("", selection: $frequency) {
                    ForEach(frequencyArray, id: \.self) { freq in
                        Text("\(freq.formatted())")
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            
            VStack {
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $startTime,
                    in: ...(Calendar.current.date(
                            byAdding: .minute,
                            value: Int((Double(frequency) * 60)),
                            to: endTime
                    
                    ) ?? Date()),
                    displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute
                )
                    .padding()
                    .background(.blue)
                
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $endTime,
                    in: (Calendar.current.date(
                        byAdding: .minute,
                        value: Int((Double(frequency) * 60)),
                        to: startTime
                    ) ?? Date())...,
                    displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute
                )
                    .padding()
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 15
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add an `onChange()` modifier for startTime, endTime and frequency and then apply the logic you described above there.

Comment: I asked how to make the date picker itself not allow a user to select a time that doesn't match the interval, like the code I posted does now with regards to the specified range. "Apply the logic you described" is unhelpful at best.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in two parts:

1. Apparently because a DatePicker has a defined range, you cannot alter that range to only allow choices based on an interval.
2. That being said, you can do this with a function so that you ensure the correct interval is maintained. From my testing, it seems best to only run this function on the endTime as running on both the startTime and endTime seems to cause issues with it trying to calculate over and over again, especially since for my purposes I have more than just this one check running.

Also, contrary to the one comment posted, you do not want to do this "onChange" because you'd have to have triplicate code (one for the frequency, one for startTime and one for endTime). Instead, simply use an EmtpyView() with a .task modifier so it's always watching for changes.

Here's the function:

```
func setClosestTime() {

    var timeAhead = Date()
    var timeBefore = Date()

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: -600, by: -15) {
        let dateCalc = Calendar.current.date(
                        byAdding: .minute,
                        value: i,
                        to: endTime
                        ) ?? Date()
        let timeCheck = (dateCalc.timeIntervalSince(startTime) / 3600).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (Double(frequency) ?? 0))
        if timeCheck == 0 {
            timeBefore = dateCalc
            break
        } // End If
    } // End For Loop

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: 600, by: 15) {
        let dateCalc = Calendar.current.date(
                        byAdding: .minute,
                        value: i,
                        to: endTime
                        ) ?? Date()
        let timeCheck = (dateCalc.timeIntervalSince(startTime) / 3600).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (Double(frequency) ?? 0))
        if timeCheck == 0 {
            timeAhead = dateCalc
            break
        }
    } // End For Loop

    if timeAhead.timeIntervalSince(endTime) < endTime.timeIntervalSince(timeBefore) {
        endTime = timeAhead
    } else {
        endTime = timeBefore
    }
} // End Func
```

What we are doing is using stride to loop in increments of 15 (backwards and forwards) and when the first match is found, set either the timeAhead or timeBefore variable.

Once both of these variables have been set, we compare the difference between the times to see which one is shorter and then set the endTime variable. This ensures that the time match will always be the closest to the time the user has chosen, while still maintaining our intervals.

To use this solution, write an if statement to check if the interval is set correctly and if not, run a task on an EmptyView().

Here's how:

```
if !((endTime.timeIntervalSince(startTime) / 3600).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (Double(frequency) ?? 0)) == 0) {
    VStack {
        EmptyView()
    }
    .task {
        setClosestTime()
    }
}
```